# ArgumentError in ContactsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting an error when I visit the page: `localhost:3000/contacts`

The error, details and the source code is provided below.

***wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)***

**Extracted source (around line #4):**

```
2  attribute :name,      :validate => true
3  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
4  attribute :message
5  attribute :nickname,  :captcha => true
```

**model.rb**

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "HsbNoid",
      :to => "iamhsb001@gmail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

**Code for controller**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
     def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(conact_params)
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :new
    end
  end
  private
  def conact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

Comment: What **error** do you get? Please post a complete stack trace.

Comment: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Comment: “wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)”—is by no means a stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

In `model.rb` line 4, you forgot to add a ','. This should be `attribute :message,`

Comment: Now i get SyntaxError in ContactsController#new in this line  "attribute :nickname,  :captcha => true" and the error is syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' attribute :nickname, :captcha => true ^